# Echad Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

181 years after Yitzchak's birth, Yosef is released from the dungeon.  (Gotta stretch those mi yodeya muscles)

Answer (score 1):

If we are stretching muscles well here is another muscle stretcher that is appropriate to the time of the year we are in.

After Achashveroshes 180 day party he began another 7 day party for the people of Shushan for 7 days. This party began on the **181st day**

Answer (score 1):

Gematria of:

"פני האהל" - "The front of the Tent" ([Last week's parsha](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15565&p=3) - Ex. 26:9)